# How to set the background colour of every cell in a HandsOnTable?

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I have a HandsOnTable table and would like to set the background colour of every cell, without providing a renderer function or the like. I tried copying the process that their [Science demo](http://jsfiddle.net/handsoncode/g1hnaxtt/) uses but my table has formatting on the values and that gets lost with their renderer function code.

My version of the renderer:

```
var footerRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.backgroundColor = '#EEE';
    td.style.textAlign = 'right';
}
```

To clarify: The problem here is that using a renderer function with HandsOnTable appear to wipe out formatting which has been applied by the properties of the table, when something simple like changing the background colour of a cell is required.

Comment: possible to use vanilla js?

Comment: Not sure how to identify the one particular element I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, this does not appear to be documented: Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this.  However, the cells function is probably the best.

**Option 1**

Step 1:  Set up your handsontable:

```
var container = document.getElementById('Element_ID');
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: <yourdataArray>,
  autoRowSize:false,
  autoWrapRow:true,
  autoRowSize: false
});
```

Step 2:  Update the handsontable settings using the cells function.  The cells function will go through each row and cell in the table

```
 // update spreadsheet setting
 hot.updateSettings({
     cells: function (row, col, prop) {                        
          var cell = hot.getCell(row,col);   // get the cell for the row and column                                                                                                                
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";  // set the background color
     }
 });
```

**Option 2**

I recommend the cells function over this, but this does demonstrate other ways of doing the same thing.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example1'), options);
var rows=hot.countRows();  // get the count of the rows in the table
var cols=hot.countCols();  // get the count of the columns in the table.
for(var row=0; row<rows; row++){  // go through each row of the table
    for(var col=0; col<cols; col++){  // go through each column of the row
        var cell = hot.getCell(row,col);  
        cell.style.background = "#00FF90";
    }
}
hot.render();  // ensure the table is refreshed.
```